# Pandas Sort - Issues in keeping order

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting

I have a `df` like this,

```
    param       per     per_date    per_num             
0   XYZ         1.0     2018-10-01  11.0                
1   XYZ         2.0     2017-08-01  15.25               
2   XYZ         1.0     2019-10-01  11.25
3   XYZ         2.0     2019-08-01  15.71 
4   XYZ         3.0     2020-10-01  NaN 
5   MMG         1.0     2021-10-01  12.50                          
6   MMG         2.0     2021-10-01  11.75               
7   MMG         3.0     2011-01-01  NaN                
8   ZZZ         4.0     2023-01-01  19.00 
9   ZZZ         3.0     2014-01-01  13.00
10  MMM         1.0     2016-03-01  12.01
11  MMM         2.0     2019-01-01  16.00
12  ZZZ         1.0     2009-06-01  12.50
13  ZZZ         2.0     2018-01-01  19.00
```

I need an output sorted like this,

```
        param       per     per_date    per_num 
    0   MMG         1.0     2021-10-01  12.50                          
    1   MMG         2.0     2021-10-01  11.75               
    2   MMG         3.0     2011-01-01  NaN  
    3   MMM         1.0     2016-03-01  12.01
    4   MMM         2.0     2019-01-01  16.00
    5   XYZ         1.0     2018-10-01  11.0                
    6   XYZ         2.0     2017-08-01  15.25               
    7   XYZ         1.0     2019-10-01  11.25
    8   XYZ         2.0     2019-08-01  15.71 
    9   XYZ         3.0     2020-10-01  NaN 
    10  ZZZ         1.0     2009-06-01  12.50
    11  ZZZ         2.0     2018-01-01  19.00              
    12  ZZZ         4.0     2023-01-01  19.00 
    13  ZZZ         3.0     2014-01-01  13.00
```

However, when I do sort,

```
df= df.sort_values(['param', 'per']).reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

I get,(not what I want)

```
   param  per   per_date    per_num
0   MMG   1.0   2021-10-01  12.50
1   MMG   2.0   2021-10-01  11.75
2   MMG   3.0   2011-01-01  NaN
3   MMM   1.0   2016-03-01  12.01
4   MMM   2.0   2019-01-01  16.00
5   XYZ   1.0   2018-10-01  11.00
6   XYZ   1.0   2019-10-01  11.25
7   XYZ   2.0   2017-08-01  15.25
8   XYZ   2.0   2019-08-01  15.71
9   XYZ   3.0   2020-10-01  NaN
10  ZZZ   1.0   2009-06-01  12.50
11  ZZZ   2.0   2018-01-01  19.00
12  ZZZ   3.0   2014-01-01  13.00
13  ZZZ   4.0   2023-01-01  19.00
```

If you see above in original `df` `xyz` has `per` values 1,2 and then starts again with 1,2,3 they are two different categories. I want to keep that order as is. However, `ZZZ` is all in one order, so one category,, but order is not same and need ordering for that. How can I do it in pandas?

Appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want. You want to sort everything except rows that have `XYZ`?

Comment: @ScottBoston No, I cannot use `per_date` to keep the ordering :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

```
df.assign(sortkey=df.groupby('param')
                    .apply(lambda x:x.duplicated(['param','per']).cumsum())
                    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))\
  .sort_values(['param','sortkey','per'])
```

Output:

```
   param  per    per_date  per_num  sortkey
5    MMG  1.0  2021-10-01    12.50        0
6    MMG  2.0  2021-10-01    11.75        0
7    MMG  3.0  2011-01-01      NaN        0
10   MMM  1.0  2016-03-01    12.01        0
11   MMM  2.0  2019-01-01    16.00        0
0    XYZ  1.0  2018-10-01    11.00        0
1    XYZ  2.0  2017-08-01    15.25        0
2    XYZ  1.0  2019-10-01    11.25        1
3    XYZ  2.0  2019-08-01    15.71        2
4    XYZ  3.0  2020-10-01      NaN        2
12   ZZZ  1.0  2009-06-01    12.50        0
13   ZZZ  2.0  2018-01-01    19.00        0
9    ZZZ  3.0  2014-01-01    13.00        0
8    ZZZ  4.0  2023-01-01    19.00        0
```

Comment: thank you, but if you see `XYZ`'s order, second values are switched.

Comment: Just add "-" in front of df.groupby (sortkey=-df.groupby...)

Comment: @ScottBoston Awesome! now yours has the correct ordering. Please feel free to edit the title as needed for future searches for this type of sorting.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Categorical`

```
df.param = pd.Categorical(df.param, categories = df.param.unique())
df = df.sort_values(['param', 'per']).reset_index(drop = True)
df
Out[348]: 
   param  per    per_date  per_num
0    XYZ  1.0  2018-10-01    11.00
1    XYZ  1.0  2019-10-01    11.25
2    XYZ  2.0  2017-08-01    15.25
3    XYZ  2.0  2019-08-01    15.71
4    XYZ  3.0  2020-10-01      NaN
5    MMG  1.0  2021-10-01    12.50
6    MMG  2.0  2021-10-01    11.75
7    MMG  3.0  2011-01-01      NaN
8    ZZZ  1.0  2009-06-01    12.50
9    ZZZ  2.0  2018-01-01    19.00
10   ZZZ  3.0  2014-01-01    13.00
11   ZZZ  4.0  2023-01-01    19.00
12   MMM  1.0  2016-03-01    12.01
13   MMM  2.0  2019-01-01    16.00
```

Update

```
df.param = pd.Categorical(df.param, categories = df.param.unique())

df['Key']=df.groupby(['param','per']).cumcount()
df = df.sort_values(['param','Key', 'per']).reset_index(drop = True).drop('Key',1)
df
Out[375]: 
   param  per    per_date  per_num
0    XYZ  1.0  2018-10-01    11.00
1    XYZ  2.0  2017-08-01    15.25
2    XYZ  3.0  2020-10-01      NaN
3    XYZ  1.0  2019-10-01    11.25
4    XYZ  2.0  2019-08-01    15.71
5    MMG  1.0  2021-10-01    12.50
6    MMG  2.0  2021-10-01    11.75
7    MMG  3.0  2011-01-01      NaN
8    ZZZ  1.0  2009-06-01    12.50
9    ZZZ  2.0  2018-01-01    19.00
10   ZZZ  3.0  2014-01-01    13.00
11   ZZZ  4.0  2023-01-01    19.00
12   MMM  1.0  2016-03-01    12.01
13   MMM  2.0  2019-01-01    16.00
```

Comment: @user9431057 combine both method ?

Comment: Awesome, almost touchdown, but second `XYZ`'s `per` order is `3,1,2`.

Comment: @user9431057 it is 123 and 12 not 312

Comment: if you look at close, `XYZ`'s `per_num` 1,2,3 set should have `11.25, 15.71, NaN` and 1,2 set should have `11.0, 15.25`. However, yours 1,2,3 has `11.0, 15.25, NaN` and 1,2 set has `11.25, 15.71`. I meant `15.71` and `15.25` are switched.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
df.assign(sortkey=-df.groupby(['param','per']).cumcount()).sort_values(['param','sortkey','per']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: @ScottBoston That's not what I get.  The negative sign in front of df.groupby keeps the original XYZ order.

Comment: Ooh.. I didn't see the negative.  You are correct.  Deleting comment now.

Comment: And, that is pretty awesome solution.  +1

Comment: @screenpaver nice and it is one liner, however, ordering of values switched like how WeNYoBen  has.

Comment: @user9431057 Hmm.  I get the same order as shown in the accepted answer. Be sure to put a negative sign in front of df.groupby.

Answer (score 0):

you need to 1st group by param and per and assign unique per value to one grouper. Then again group by param and grouper and sort each group by param and per

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

df = pd.DataFrame([['XYZ', 1.0, Timestamp('2018-10-01 00:00:00'), 11.0], ['XYZ', 2.0, Timestamp('2017-08-01 00:00:00'), 15.25], ['XYZ', 1.0, Timestamp('2019-10-01 00:00:00'), 11.25], ['XYZ', 2.0, Timestamp('2019-08-01 00:00:00'), 15.71], ['MMG', 1.0, Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'), 12.5], ['MMG', 2.0, Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'), 11.75], ['ZZZ', 4.0, Timestamp('2023-01-01 00:00:00'), 19.0], ['ZZZ', 3.0, Timestamp('2014-01-01 00:00:00'), 13.0], ['MMM', 1.0, Timestamp('2016-03-01 00:00:00'), 12.01], ['MMM', 2.0, Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00'), 16.0], ['ZZZ', 1.0, Timestamp('2009-06-01 00:00:00'), 12.5], ['ZZZ', 2.0, Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'), 19.0]], columns=('param', 'per', 'per_date', 'per_num'))

df["grouper"] = df.groupby(["param", "per"]).cumcount()

df.groupby(["param", "grouper"])\
.apply(lambda g: g.sort_values(["param", "per"]))\
.reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Result**

```
param  per   per_date  per_num  grouper
0    MMG  1.0 2021-10-01    12.50        0
1    MMG  2.0 2021-10-01    11.75        0
2    MMM  1.0 2016-03-01    12.01        0
3    MMM  2.0 2019-01-01    16.00        0
4    XYZ  1.0 2018-10-01    11.00        0
5    XYZ  2.0 2017-08-01    15.25        0
6    XYZ  1.0 2019-10-01    11.25        1
7    XYZ  2.0 2019-08-01    15.71        1
8    ZZZ  1.0 2009-06-01    12.50        0
9    ZZZ  2.0 2018-01-01    19.00        0
10   ZZZ  3.0 2014-01-01    13.00        0
11   ZZZ  4.0 2023-01-01    19.00        0
```

Comment: Still, `ZZZ` is not sorted.